# Ruby on Rails calling methods of objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, calling-convention

There is something I don't understand about ruby.

```
@items.each do |item| 
  item.column
end
```

will work and return me the value for that column in rails. but

```
item = @items[some_item_id]
item.column
```

will give me a method not found exception for nil.
Both times I get the object but only with the first I can access the rails data methodes.

What do those dashes |...| do and how do I access such methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gathers **all elements** inside `@items` for passage into a block:

```
@items.each
```

`#each` will work on hashes, arrays, and other enumerables.

---

This selects **a specific element** inside `@items`:

```
@items[some_item_id]
```

The square brackets are a method (named `#[]`) for element reference in both hashes and arrays. If you get a `MethodNotFound` error, it means `@items` is not a hash or array and doesn't have a method named `#[]`.

If `@items` is a collection of ActiveRecord objects and you want to select one by ID, use:

```
@items.find(some_item_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because in second case you pass incorrect `some_item_id`, so `@items[some_item_id]` doesn't find appropriate `item` and returns `nil`
.

Answer (score 1):

```
@items.each do |item| 
 item.column
end
```

In above block ruby iterate over records that fetched from database So you are not getting any nil error. But in second case you are trying to fetch record from their index in `@items`. It's failing because some of your records get deleted from database. OR it will fail on last record only because index start with 0 and id of a table from 1. So miss match occurs when we call from index.

Answer (score 0):

You need to appreciate how [ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) works with Rails

---

**ActiveRecord**

What you're doing when you call `@items.each do ...` is looping through the [*collection*](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) of `Item` objects in the `@items` variable. As ruby deals with looping with a [code block](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_blocks.html).

For lack of a better explanation, code blocks are essentially small in-line methods, which have their own local variables, and can be called when using loops (much like most other programming languages). The most important thing to note here is the data you have in the `@items` variable.

--

**Data**

Rails is an [object-orientated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) framework (by virtue of being built on Ruby). This means that your `@instance` variables will basically treated as *objects*, which means you have to be very careful when populating them with the respective data:

[image]

The bottom line is, as `Marek` stipulated, you cannot set `@items = Item.all`, and then call an item by its id from an array. The `object` you're dealing with *isn't* an array - it's an object, and as such, you'll have to use the methods available to you to access the data you need.

There are two ways you can access the data you want:

> 1. Use the `find` method
> 2. Only look up particular `Item` records

If you don't mind being hacky, you could use the ActiveRecord `.find` method:

```
<% item = @items.find [your_item_id] %>
<%= item.column %>
```

This will give you the ability to look up the particular item within the collection of `@items` you have.

Alternatively, you'll want to do things "properly" by setting the relevant `@item` object in your controller:

```
#app/controllers/items_controller.rb
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @item = Item.find "your_id"
   end
end
```

Comment: Why would it be hacky? Because it is not in the controller? I am actually trying to get the name of an item which is linked in a different collection of objects. So I have to access it in the view. I can only collect a limited set of necessary items in the controller but I still have to select them in the view. The @items.find[some_id] doesn't work though. I think because id is the position in the record and not the id of the rails model object. Did you mean Item.find rather than @items.find

Comment: Yep, it would be hacky for not being in the controller :) Nope - if you have `@items`, you'll be able to use `.find` on the collection - ActiveRecord does the rest

Comment: Yes it just didn't work at first because my data had an error. SQL constraints would be nice to have. Is there a simple do only if not null shorthand syntax for something like  Item.find(x) unless nil but working. like a try catch block but without multiple lines (I come from java)

Comment: Wow you've lost me there! What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry a bit confusing. I figured out what I wanted already. Never mind.